# How many increasing numbers can be formed.

Tags: combinatorics

A number N is called increasing number, if the digits of N are not in decreasing order.
For example: 1123.

We have a number N, where N = 123 and size K.The task is to find the number of increasing numbers of size K that can be formed using the digits of N.

For Example:

    `If K=3, then the possible number is only 123

    If K=4, then the possible numbers are 1123, 1223, 1233

    If K=5, then the possible numbers are 11123 11223, 11233, 12223, 12233, 12333`

It will be really helpful, if I know the number of possible sequence for a given K

Comment: Can you clarify if all the digits in $N$ must be used?

Comment: @CalvinLin check first example (when k = 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is based on the assumption that all the digits of $N$ must be used, which is why there is only 1 solution for $K=3$.)

**Approach used:** [Stars and bars](https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/stars-and-bars/).

**Hint:** Think about organizing $n-1$ +'s and $K-n$ -'s, where $n$ is the number of distinct digits in $N$. Create a bijection between such a sequence, and a valid increasing number that you are looking for.

For example, with $n=3$, $K=4$, we have $n-1=2$ and $K-n = 1$, and the sequences are:

$$ ++-, +-+, -++. $$
This corresponds to

$$ 1233, 1223, 1123 $$

---

Hence, conclude that the answer is $ { (K -n) + (n-1)  \choose (n-1)} = { K-1 \choose n-1} $.

Comment: For whatever n and K, if the digits are 0's and 1's, then there will be only one increasing sequence right ?.
(correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @yuv60 Not quite. The idea is to create a bijection between these 2. Let me rename the digits 0 and 1 to - and + instead.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks

Comment: This answer is wrong... In the particular case of the problem, $n=3$. So when $K=5$, then the result would be $4$ choose $3$, which is $4$(the answer should be $6$). The correct answer is $K-1$ choose $2$.

Comment: @shooting-squirrel Sorry, I did the binomial coefficient wrongly. Just edited it.